CodeIgniter\Router\RouteCollection::__construct(): Argument #3 ($routing) - Codeigniter 4
I use codeigniter version 4 (4.0)
This result after I run this command. I follow here
composer update && cp vendor/codeigniter4/framework/public/index.php public/index.php && cp vendor/codeigniter4/framework/spark spark

then try php spark serve, the error below appears.
CodeIgniter\Router\RouteCollection::__construct(): Argument #3 ($routing) must be of type Config\Routing, null given, called in D:\Belajar Web\codeigniter\my-diary-ci4\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\Config\Services.php on line 622

if I browse the service.php file

please help me to solve this problem in my local computer, thank you

The error looks like the route config is not there. What is the content of your Routing.php and Route.php config-files? Furthermore (if you updated from 4.0 to 4.5) did you follow the upgrade instructions for all version upgrades? Which are a lot.

here is my routes.php file https://pastecode.io/s/56yqkn4e

CodeIgniter changed it's route-file-setup a few versions back. It is now 2 files Routing.php and Route.php and you are using just one (old) routes.php. Change your route-files to model the new setup and check if the error persists.

I have followed this method https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/installation/upgrade_440.html#app-config-events-php, php spark serve is successfully run on http://localhost:8080/ but finally my main page becomes a blank page.
